# Как запустить микросервисы?

Tags: java, spring, java-ee, spring-security, микросервисы

Недавно начал учить тему "создание микросервисов" с Spring.
Я прочёл много статей про эту тему и понял, что микросервисы — это лишь маленькие приложения отделенные друг от друга, которые взаимодействуют между собой например, протоколом REST...

Это всё, конечно, замечательно, но я так и не понял как запускать эти самые микросервисы, чтобы они взаимодействовали между собой. Они, по моему мнению, должны быть поочерёдно запущены в разных портах (исправьте, если ошибаюсь).

Как вообще запускают приложение на микросервисной архитектуре? Что используют? Возможно ли запустить микросервисы без Docker и т.п? Или всё происходит, как я описал выше?

Comment: Микросервисы запускаются также как и другие приложения на Спринге. Запускать их можно как заблагорассудится. Контейнеры это лишь часть инфраструктуры которая может помочь доставлять код до нужного места и без труда развернуть его там. Но для разработки локально в этом нет никакой необходимости, как и для разработки небольших сервисов, которые деплоятся на одну несчастную машину,  как и для разработки монолитов это также необязательно.

Comment: Да как угодно можно запускать - хоть в контейнере, если это позволяет сделать окружение, хоть на виртуалке, хоть все сервисы на одном сервере, но на разных портах, конечно же.

Comment: Не усложняйте свою жизнь. Можете представить себе докер как современный экзешник. Но если есть современный то сущетвует и классический экзешник который запускается как обычно. Разница классического вы будите настраивать всё.

Comment: Представляю, как будет тормозить компьютер, если микросервисов будет много. Так и должно быть?

Comment: Представляю, как будет тормозить компьютер, если микросервисов будет много. Так и должно быть? - зависит от задач. Если сервисы загружают комп  то да так и должно быть. Если сервисы работают в фоне и ничего не делают, то думаю нет так не должно быть

Comment: @Аркадий как правило для каждого микросервиса выделяется 1 машина. Более того, у 1 сервиса может быть множество инстансов и каждый инстанс имеет отдельную машину. Советую вам почитать книгу по микросервисам, чтобы лучше понять для чего они нужны и как развертываются. Например, Spring Microservices in Action.